# Reducing array of items into a single array list

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is my array if items that I want to reduce it to a single list of arrays..

```
var input=[
    [
        2
    ],
    [
        3,
        13
    ],
    [
        4,
        14
    ],
    [
        5,
        15,
        25,
        35
    ]
]

var output=[
    2,
    3,
    13,
    4,
    14,
    5,
    15,
    25,
    35
]
```

My code:

```
  function reduceArray(item){
                  for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){
                      return i;
                  }
              }
    var result=result.map((item)=>{
                   if(item.length>0){
                       return reduceArray(item);
                   }else{
                       return item;
                   }
               })
```

which produces the same result.Can anyone please figure out where I'm doing wrong or any other approach to achieve this..Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input.reduce(function(a, x) { return a.concat(x); });
// => [2, 3, 13, 4, 14, 5, 15, 25, 35]
```

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) sets the accumulator to the first element (or a starting value if provided), then calls the function with the accumulator and each successive element. The function we provide is concatenation. If we say `input` is `[a, b, c]`, then the above command will be equivalent to `a.concat(b).concat(c)`. `[concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)` produces a new array by smushing two or more arrays together.

EDIT: Actually, there is another possible answer:

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply(input[0], array.slice(1));
// => [2, 3, 13, 4, 14, 5, 15, 25, 35]
```

This directly calls `concat` with multiple arguments; if `input` is again `[a, b, c]`, then this is equivalent to `a.concat(b, c)`. [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) calls a function with a given receiver and arguments; [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) will give us just a part of the array, in this case everything starting from the first element (which we need to chop off since it needs to be the receiver of the `concat` call).

Comment: I am quiet sure this is best answer among all other answers, but... A nice little explanation will help others understand what is happening.. :)

Answer (score 2):

One liner would be

```
input = [[2],[3,13],[4,14],[5,15,25,35]];
[].concat.apply([],input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash's flattenDeep()](https://lodash.com/docs#flattenDeep)

```
_.flattenDeep([1, [2, [3, [4]], 5]]);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

User `concat`.check this for more information http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

```js
var input=[[2],[3,13],[4,14],[5,15,25,35]];
var output=[];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
  output = output.concat(input[i]);
}
console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `concat` is the perfect way

> The concat() method is used to join two or more arrays.
>   This method does not change the existing arrays, but returns a new array, containing the values of the joined arrays.

```
var newArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
{
    newArr = newArr.concat(input[i]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```